# Database Schema for email Drip application?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

Working on an email drip feature for an application. DB schema for email templates and email logs were pretty easy. I'm stuck setting up the schema for template triggers. This feature is part of a larger CRM  solution.

My current schema is based off of campaigns and triggers, the campaign defines when to send emails, the triggers define when to either remove or add a person to the campaign.

```
[CAMPAIGN]
CAMPAIGN_ID [GUID]
DELAY_DAYS [INT]
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID [GUID]

[CAMPAIGN_XREF]
ID [GUID]
PERSON_ID [GUID]
CAMPAIGN_ID [GUID]
ACTIVE_DATE [TIMESTAMP]
isACTIVE [BOOL]
```

My design is such that a drip campaign would be comprised of a bunch of email templates. Each campaign item has a delay date which is used to calculate which email to send, so if campaign A has delay days 0, 30, 60; the user would be sent emails on day 1, then in 1 month, then in 2 months. Using a scheduled task to run nightly to perform the actions and update the dates.

I'm having an issue with setting up triggers. Triggers will be based upon a person's status. So if i person is placed in the nurture status, they would be assigned to a certain campaign.

The other trigger would be based off an appointment date. This would work so if a person has an appointment scheduled in say 30 days, it would send an email 7 days prior, and if possible, 14 days prior. How to handle these items when the available send window is smaller then the campaign timeline?

The items i'm grappling with are when \ how to check if a trigger matches a lead (realtime vs scheduled task), how to handle removing them from a certain campaign?

Comment: For anyone wondering... decided not to re-invent the wheel, using www.getdrip.com pretty robust service.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using www.getdrip.com pretty robust, good API, good support. Don't re-invent the wheel.